# future composability, and boost::wait_for_all

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, c++11, future

I just read the article '[Futures Done Right](http://bartoszmilewski.com/2009/03/10/futures-done-right/)', and the main thing that c++11 promises are lacking seems to be that creating composite futures from existing ones

I'm looking right now at the documentation of [boost::wait_for_any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.reference.wait_for_any)

but consider the following example:

```
int calculate_the_answer_to_life_the_universe_and_everything()
{
    return 42;
}

int calculate_the_answer_to_death_and_anything_in_between()
{
    return 121;
}

boost::packaged_task<int> pt(calculate_the_answer_to_life_the_universe_and_everything);
boost:: future<int> fi=pt.get_future();
boost::packaged_task<int> pt2(calculate_the_answer_to_death_and_anything_in_between);
boost:: future<int> fi2=pt2.get_future();

....


int calculate_the_oscillation_of_barzoom(boost::future<int>& a, boost::future<int>& b)
{
    boost::wait_for_all(a,b);
    return a.get() + b.get();
}

boost::packaged_task<int> pt_composite(boost::bind(calculate_the_oscillation_of_barzoom, fi , fi2));
boost:: future<int> fi_composite=pt_composite.get_future();
```

What is wrong with this approach to composability? is this a valid way to achieve composability? do we need some elegant syntactic edulcorant over this pattern?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`when_any` and `when_all` are perfectly valid ways to compose futures. They both correspond to parallel composition, where the composite operation waits for either one or all the composed operations.

We also need sequential composition (which is not in Boost.Thread). This could be, for example, a `future<T>::then` function that allows you to queue up an operation that uses the future's value and runs when the future is ready. It is possible to implement this yourself, but with an efficiency tradeoff. Herb Sutter talks about this in his [recent Channel9 video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-Concurrency-and-Parallelism).

[N3428](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3428.pdf) is a draft proposal for adding these features (and more) to the C++ standard library. They are all library features and don't add any new syntax to the language. Additionally, [N3328](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3328.pdf) is a proposal to add syntax for *resumable functions* (like using `async`/`await` in C#) which will use `future<T>::then` internally.

Comment: we already have resumable functions as library in boost: see `boost::context`. the implementation of a library `when_all` would be some variadic template variant of the code example i posted? or is there some more magic that i'm missing out?

Comment: of course, all those packaged_tasks need to be submitted at some point to a thread pool or `asio::io_service` for async execution, but the semantics should not be affected if/when the computations are performed

Comment: @lurscher Implementing `when_any` solely on top of the existing library features is possible, but not necessarily efficient. I can't see any way to do it without spawning a large number of threads, blocking them on all, and waiting for one of them to wake up. On the other hand, if the operating system provides some support, there might be a much more efficient implementation possible for a standard library vendor.

Comment: @lurscher Also, Boost.Context is one possible way to implement resumable functions, and it relies on allocating multiple stacks and such. If the compiler directly supported it as a language feature, it would presumably be able to do a much better job by generating code differently. I think `when_all`, `when_any`, `future<T>::then` are basic concurrency primitives that I feel should be in the standard library. In addition, I think `async`/`await` is good syntax for exposing a transformation that the compiler can perform easily and builds on the library features.

Answer (score 3):

Points for the use of the word [*edulcorant*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/edulcorant). :)

The problem with your sample code is that you package everything up into tasks, but you never *schedule* those tasks for execution!

```
int calculate_the_answer_to_life() { ... }

int calculate_the_answer_to_death() { ... }

std::packaged_task<int()> pt(calculate_the_answer_to_life);
std::future<int> fi = pt.get_future();
std::packaged_task<int()> pt2(calculate_the_answer_to_death);
std::future<int> fi2 = pt2.get_future();

int calculate_barzoom(std::future<int>& a, std::future<int>& b)
{
    boost::wait_for_all(a, b);
    return a.get() + b.get();
}

std::packaged_task<int()> pt_composite([]{ return calculate_barzoom(fi, fi2); });
std::future<int> fi_composite = pt_composite.get_future();
```

If at this point I write

```
pt_composite();
int result = fi_composite.get();
```

***my program will block forever.*** It will never complete, because `pt_composite` is blocked on `calculate_barzoom`, which is blocked on `wait_for_all`, which is blocked on both `fi` and `fi2`, neither of which will ever complete until somebody executes `pt` or `pt2` respectively. And nobody will ever execute them, because my program is blocked!

You probably meant me to write something like this:

```
std::async(pt);
std::async(pt2);
std::async(pt_composite);
int result = fi_composite.get();
```

*This* will work. But it's extremely inefficient — we spawn three worker threads (via three calls to `async`), in order to perform two threads' worth of work. That third thread — the one running `pt_composite` — will be spawned immediately, and then *just sit there asleep* until `pt` and `pt2` have finished running. That's better than *spinning*, but it's significantly worse than *not existing*: it means that our thread pool has one fewer worker than it ought to have. In a plausible thread-pool implementation with only one thread per CPU core, and a lot of tasks coming in all the time, that means that we've got one CPU core just sitting idle, because the worker thread who was *meant* to be running on that core is currently blocked inside `wait_for_all`.

What we *want* to do is declare our intentions declaratively:

```
int calculate_the_answer_to_life() { ... }

int calculate_the_answer_to_death() { ... }

std::future<int> fi = std::async(calculate_the_answer_to_life);
std::future<int> fi2 = std::async(calculate_the_answer_to_death);
std::future<int> fi_composite = std::when_all(fi, fi2).then([](auto a, auto b) {
    assert(a.is_ready() && b.is_ready());
    return a.get() + b.get();
});

int result = fi_composite.get();
```

and then have the library and the scheduler work together to Do The Right Thing: don't spawn any worker thread that can't immediately proceed with its task. If the end-user has to write even a single line of code that explicitly sleeps, waits, or blocks, some performance is definitely being lost.

In other words: ***Spawn no worker thread before its time.***

---

Obviously it's *possible* to do all this in standard C++, without library support; that's how the library itself is implemented! But it's a huge pain to implement from scratch, with many subtle pitfalls; so that's why it's a good thing that library support seems to be coming soon.

The ISO proposal [N3428](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3428.pdf) mentioned in [Roshan Shariff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14174701/1424877) has been updated as [N3857](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3857.pdf), and [N3865](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3865.pdf) provides even more convenience functions.